# Why won't the following applescript simulate the key presses?

Tags: applescript

I don't understand why the following code won't initiate key pressing q or space. They work outside of the if statement. Please help me understand, I am very new to this.

```
if x is "705011" then
    say "Yes"
    return x
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "q"
else
    say "No"
    return x
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke " "
end if
```

Comment: Place `return x` after `tell application "System Events" to ...` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `return` statement exits the current scope. In the `run` handler it aborts the script and in a custom handler it returns to the caller.

Any code after a `return` statement is not executed.